# Makefile syntax $(A,B,C)?

Tags: makefile

Consider the following code:

```
$ANIMAL = COW PIG CHICKEN VAMPIRE

all:
        @echo $(ANIMAL, F, >.txt)
```

I strove to find a section in GNU make manual that mentions the above syntax, but I couldn't find anything related to it. What does it print and how is the syntax structured for the functionality?

Added: When a line starts with "@--" what does it mean?

```
@-- $(GEN_ENV); ...
```

Comment: This code actually seems wrong: assigning to a variable beginning with '$'?

Comment: Where did you get this code and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: 1) it doesn't print anything 2) dunno.

Comment: Actually one of my coworkers told me we were using a variation of makefile calle OPUS... Yeah maybe that's why it's difficult to find a documentation on this. :/

Comment: Then maybe you should not confuse people by tagging this as "makefile" and "gnu" but as "opus"?

Comment: @xorxorxor There are links on opus docs in my answer.. I took the responsibility and remove "gnu" tag since it's not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your addition: In regular Makefiles (read: POSIX, GNU, ...)

- a leading '@' supresses echoing of the command.
- a leading '-' says to ignore a non-zero exit status
- both can be combined, and repetitions are okay, so `@---@@@-@---echo foo` is the same as `@-echo foo`

Answer (score 0):

This is called "macro modifiers". This is not a GNU make feature. Take a look at [this chapter of OPUS make tutorial](http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm#Macro%20Modifiers). The general syntax of these modifiers:

```
$(name,modifier[,modifier]...) 

name is macro expanded, then each modifier is applied in succession to the elements of the expanded value.
```

Take a look then at [the list of modifiers](http://www.opussoftware.com/quickref/Macros.htm#Macro%20Modifiers) and it becomes clear that it forms a list of file names (truncates paths of each variable in **ANIMAL**) with .txt added. So, in your case it shoud output:

```
COW.txt PIG.txt CHICKEN.txt VAMPIRE.txt
```

PS

I looked through the reference mentioned above and don't think the first line ($ANIMAL = ) is correct since macro definition should start without $.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments it seems you are actually using OpusMake, rather than GNU make.  You can find more information about it [on the Opus Software, Inc. website](http://www.opussoftware.com/), and also in [this handy reference guide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2368143/Opus-Make-Quick-Reference).  From those sources you can see that you have an example of a *macro* employing *macro modifiers* in its expansion.

Generally speaking `$(FOO)` is expanded to the unmodified value of the variable `FOO`, while `$(FOO,mod1[,mod2[,...]]])` expands to the value of `FOO`, modified according to the modifiers you specify.  Note that you can string together any number of modifiers, and they will be applied in left-to-right order.

There's a ton of possible modifiers, but your example specifically uses two:

- The `F` modifier, which means "use just the final path component of each pathname in the variable value"
- The `>str` modifier, which means "append the text `str` to each space-separated word in the value".

Here's a quick example:

```
FOO=abc/def ghi/jkl
BAR=$(FOO,F)
BAZ=$(FOO,>.txt)
BOO=$(FOO,F,>.txt)
```

- `BAR` will have the value `def jkl` (ie, just the filename portion of each path).
- `BAZ` will have the value `abc/def.txt ghi/jkl.txt` (ie, append .txt to each space-separated word in the value)
- `BOO` will have the value `def.txt jkl.txt` (ie, first take just the filename portion of each path, then append .txt to each)